# Vertical Bar Graphs in C?

Tags: c, graph

I want to make a vertical bar graph in c, such that the user enters some marks, we take out percentage and represent it in form of a graph.
I've done this in horizontal graph. Can someone suggest for a vertical one?

It should look like this:

```
###     
###     
###  ###
###  ###
###  ###  ###  ###
###  ###  ###  ###
###  ###  ###  ###
###  ###  ###  ###
math sci  cs   chem
```

Comment: Do you mean you have actually made a Horizontal one? If so, any code?
Otherwise, surely you could just use hashes going the other way up? Maybe doubley thick. Sorry I'm just confused how you're asking one question with a demo of the other direction? EDIT: It was edited after I posted this :P The hashes were going horizontally originally..

Comment: Is this homework by any chance?

Comment: Nope.... This isn't a homework....
Just doing fun.....

Comment: Pretty decent duplicate: [how to plot a histogram in c](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/3836987/edit).

Answer (score 2):

Let's say your implementation assumes the horizontal graph is represented by a [matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_%28mathematics%29). If so, what you want can be achieved by doing a [transposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose) of said matrix.

I.E. you can achieve what you want by using a reversed for loop.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Can you please suggest me some tutorials/links where I can learn more about Matrix in C. Actually, I have just began C few days ago. Hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 0):

Find the tallest datapoint, and use that as a 0 in a for loop.  Print out the row.  Keep printing rows until you hit the next highest datapoint (so the graph would be printed for index (tallestheight-heightofcurrentdatapoint) on down.

```
#       i = 0
#
#  # <--------i = tallest - current = 5-3 (starts at i = 2)
#  #  # <-----i = tallest - current = 5-2 (starts at i = 3)
#  #  #
```